# Why is Eurail more expensive than Interrail?

Tags: price, eurail, interrail

I was looking into planning a train trip with a friend from abroad and I realized that getting a Rail pass for him would be a lot more expensive - 371 EUR vs. 253 EUR.

Is there a reason why non-European residents are heavily penalized? Or perhaps the two passes aren't actually fully equivalent?

Comment: Maybe it's not that the ones are penalized but that the others are subsidized?

Comment: @martin.koeberl subsidized by the EU? Could be a good answer by I can't find any information about this.

Comment: I doubt it would be subsidized by the EU since it is available to non EEA nationals.

Comment: I was surprised to learn that both were operated by the same company (tells you how out-of-date my knowledge of this is!). Originally, they were separate offers with a completely distinct history and I would be curious to know whether the marketing has been integrated. It doesn't fully explain *why* of course but they had different priorities, different markets and possibly different agreements with rail operators.

Comment: An Interrail pass is not valid in the country of residence of the pass holder. So they have slightly different validity terms.

Comment: And if you actually select the same travel class for both passes, you get 371 vs 253.

Comment: @dunni It is valid in the residence country for one trip to the border and one trip from the border

Comment: It may also just be a matter of "revenue management" -- that is, since travelers from outside Europe are already spending significant money to get themselves to and from Europe, they will probably be willing to pay higher prices for a rail pass, because it will be a proportionally smaller part of their total travel budget.

Comment: I am amazed this question has not been closed yet, it is impossible to give a factual answer without interviewing those behind the selling and marketing strategees. And even then you might not get an answer beyond 'because that is the way it is.'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is more likely to be historical, rather than a practical difference with the two passes. As a matter of fact, [Interrail](http://www.interrail.eu/en/trains-europe/railway-companies) actually covers more countries than [Eurail](http://www.eurail.com/en/eurail-passes) with Great Britain being the difference. (note as of 2020, the UK is part of Interrail and Eurail, and both programs cover the same 33 countries)

[The Eurail-plan was started in 1959 as a way to originally get American visitors to visit European countries.](http://www.switzerlandbyrail.com/eurail/eurail_system.htm) Interrail on the other hand was started in [1972](http://www.eurailgroup.org/%7E/media/Images/marketing_by_carriers/InterRail%20Media%20Kit%202012%20_3.ashx) and originally it was only available for the European youth under 21. Since then both passes have changed a lot and only recently since 2007 have they been sold by the same company. Essentially they started as different products with different purposes during different times.